# Command prompt get unselected after using Pyglet to play audio in Python 3 in Windows 10

Tags: python, audio, pyglet

Need to take user input immediately after the code is done playing all the sounds. But can't because command prompt will loose focus when the sounds files are loaded into memory, and hence can't take input from keyboard.

Tried using pyglet.app.run() and pyglet.app.exit()

These two functions don't seem to work and don't really understand how they are supposed to work either.

```
import pyglet
import time
import random
import queue

pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
pyglet.have_avbin=True

music1 = pyglet.media.StaticSource(pyglet.media.load('1.ogg'))
music2 = pyglet.media.StaticSource(pyglet.media.load('2.ogg'))

def play1():
    music1.play()

def play2():
    music2.play()

def play3():
    music1.play()
    time.sleep(0.15)
    music.play()

def play4():
    music2.play()
    time.sleep(0.15)
    music2.play()

key = 2
Q = queue.Queue()

def inp():
    i = key

    while i > 0:
        i = i - 1
        time.sleep(1)
        x = random.randint(1, 4)
        print(x)
        if x == 1:
            Q.put(1)
            play1()
        if x == 2:
            Q.put(2)
            play2()
        if x == 3:
            Q.put(3)
            play3()
        if x == 4:
            Q.put(4)
            play4()


def user():
    h = input("Enter")
    print(h)

inp()
user()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "command line loses focus"? What OS are you on? Which Python version?

Comment: Comman prompt windows gets unselected.
WIndows 10. Python 3.

Comment: I don't know [pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home). You could try other audio libraries or maybe split the playing part into another script/thread/process in order to suppress the focus-loss issue. Or find a way to change the focus back to your CMD window (pywin32?). Or solve the [issue upstream](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/issues?status=new&status=open).